How to get Blazor WASM component rendered in existing ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app
I was following this tutorial to try and create a new Blazor wasm project and integrate it into an existing ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app.  If I do exactly as the tutorial shows, I can get the example working fine. But as soon as I pull the same code over to my existing solution the Counter component does not render in my .cshtml view.
My startup class is a bit more complicated, so I don't know if that would cause a conflict. For example, in the tutorial, the app is an instance of a WebApplication while in mine, the app is an instance of IApplicationBuilder. Since WebApplication implements IApplicationBuilder, I would think that would be fine. But I'm not sure if something else in the startup might be causing a problem.
Here's my startup class:
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        SiteConfigurationSettings.LoadConfiguration(Configuration);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecific", p => p.WithOrigins(origins)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()));

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                // provides model binding for json that doesn't bind to a strongly-typed model
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new JsonValueTypeModelBinderProvider());
            })
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });

        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });

        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });

        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataProtectionDbContext>()
            .SetApplicationName("FHREC");

        services.AddRazorPages();
        var mvcBuilder = services.AddControllersWithViews();

        #if DEBUG
        mvcBuilder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        #endif

        // configures file path for static web (js, css) assets
        services.ConfigureOptions<StaticFilePathResolver>();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.RegisterFHServices(new RecRegistrySpec());
        
        services.InitializeAutoMapper();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHostFiltering();
        
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }

        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot"))
        });

        app.UseSession();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            await next();
        });
        
        app.UseCookiePolicy(
            new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
            });

        var startupManager = new PortalStartupManager(app);
        app = startupManager.RegisterErrorHandler();

        app.UseHsts();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                "default",
                "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapRazorPages(); 
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
        });

        startupManager.Startup();
    }
}

And when referencing the FWBlazor project's component in the view.
@using FWBlazor.Pages

<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />


According to the article, you should use the app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles(); app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); directly behind the  if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) code block. Don't use the  endpoints.MapFallbackToFile.

Yes, that is different.  However, MapFallbackToFile isn't available in the app.  I came across an article by Rick Strahl that pointed me to adding it to the endpoints.  https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Jul/12/Handling-SPA-Fallback-Paths-in-a-Generic-ASPNET-Core-Server
